# scaling filter - adjusted height with minimum value

Tags: ffmpeg

Is it possible to use in scale filter such formula
`scale=w='t':h='max(-1, 2)'`?
Where I want to have
`h='max(-1, 2)'` - means adjusted to 'w' parameter, but minimum value is 2?

Answer (score 0):

`-n` is shorthand for proportional scaling to a target dimension divisible by `n`. But this numerical value is only interpreted as such when it's the evaluated value of the expression. `max(-1, 2)` will always evaluate to `2`.

Instead, substitute with the expression for proportional height: `h=max(ow/dar,2)`

Comment: Ok so in h='max(-1, 2)' the "-1" will be not interpreted as h=-1?

Comment: Correct...........